# Как пишется «воинов – односельчан»?

Tags: орфография

Как правильно пишется: «... воинов – односельчан, погибших во время ВОВ...», или «... воинов-односельчан, погибших во время ВОВ...»?

Answer (score 2):

Правильно: **воинов-односельчан**, погибших во время ВОВ...

Здесь дефисное написание приложения в постпозиции, словосочетание часто применяется в таких текстах, например:

Памятник воинам-односельчанам, погибшим в годы Великой Отечественной войны, установлен в поселке  9 Мая 1984 года.